# How to create a search script for image links with captions using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, event-handling

I am trying to create a search script using jQuery. I am trying to make the search box filter photos based on their respective caption and the should photos filter in real-time as you type, and the displayed photos should match the search.
Here is my HTML and Javascript code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Photo Gallery</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/lightbox/css/lightbox.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class=container>

            <!-- <form action="form-field"> -->
            <input type="search" id="site-search" placeholder="Search(16pt)">
            <!-- </form> -->

            <div class="images-container">
                <a href= "photos/01.jpg" data-alt="Hay Bales"data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the countryside past some straw fields."><img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Image 1"></a>
                <a href= "photos/02.jpg" data-alt ="Lake"data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="The lake was so calm today. We had a great view of the snow on the mountains from here."><img src="photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Image 2"></a>
                <a href= "photos/03.jpg" data-alt="Canyon"data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="I hiked to the top of the mountain and got this picture of the canyon and trees below."><img src="photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Image 3"></a>
                <a href= "photos/04.jpg" data-alt="Iceberg"data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="It was amazing to see an iceberg up close, it was so cold but didn’t snow today. "><img src="photos/thumbnails/04.jpg" alt="Image 4"></a>
                <a href= "photos/05.jpg" data-alt="Desert"data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="The red cliffs were beautiful. It was really hot in the desert but we did a lot of walking through the canyons."><img src="photos/thumbnails/05.jpg" alt="Image 5"></a>
                <a href= "photos/06.jpg" data-alt="Fall"data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Fall is coming, I love when the leaves on the trees start to change color."><img src="photos/thumbnails/06.jpg" alt="Image 6"></a>
                <a href= "photos/07.jpg" data-alt="Plantation"data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="I drove past this plantation yesterday, everything is so green!"><img src="photos/thumbnails/07.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
                <a href= "photos/08.jpg" data-alt="Dunes"data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My summer vacation to the Oregon Coast. I love the sandy dunes!"><img src="photos/thumbnails/08.jpg" alt="Image 8"></a>
                <a href= "photos/09.jpg" data-alt="Countryside Lane"data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="We enjoyed a quiet stroll down this countryside lane."><img src="photos/thumbnails/09.jpg" alt="Image 9"></a>
                <a href= "photos/10.jpg" data-alt="Sunset"data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Sunset at the coast! The sky turned a lovely shade of orange."><img src="photos/thumbnails/10.jpg" alt="Image 10"></a>
                <a href= "photos/11.jpg" data-alt="Cave"data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="I did a tour of a cave today and the view of the landscape below was breathtaking."><img src="photos/thumbnails/11.jpg" alt="Image 11"></a>
                <a href= "photos/12.jpg" data-alt="Blueballs"data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="I walked through this meadow of bluebells and got a good view of the snow on the mountain before the fog came in."><img src="photos/thumbnails/12.jpg" alt="Image 12"></a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lightbox/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

$("#site-search").keyup(function() {
    let searchInput=$("#site-search").val().toLowerCase();
    $('a').each(function(element){
        let caption=$(element).attr('data-title').toLowerCase();
        if (caption.includes(searchInput)) {
            $(element).show();
        }
    });
});
```

For some reason I am getting an error saying that toLowercase is undefined. Why is that? Could you guys make suggestions to my code to fix the error? I'm kinda stuck and don't know if I'm on the right track or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is not the object. It is the index. You can use `this` (or add a second parameter) instead of `element` variable.

```
$("#site-search").keyup(function() {
  let searchInput = $("#site-search").val().toLowerCase();
  $('.images-container > a').each(function(index, element) {
    let caption = $(element).attr('data-title').toLowerCase();

    if (caption.includes(searchInput)) {
      $(element).show();
    } else {
      $(element).hide(); //Hide elements that dont include the search word.
    }
  });
});
```

```js
$("#site-search").keyup(function() {
  let searchInput = $("#site-search").val().toLowerCase();
  $('.images-container > a').each(function(index, element) {
    let caption = $(element).attr('data-title').toLowerCase();

    if (caption.includes(searchInput)) {
      $(element).show();
    } else {
      $(element).hide(); //Hide elements that dont include the search word.
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="site-search" placeholder="Search(16pt)">

<div class="images-container">
  <a href="photos/01.jpg" data-alt="Hay Bales" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the countryside past some straw fields."><img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Image 1"></a>
  <a href="photos/02.jpg" data-alt="Lake" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="The lake was so calm today. We had a great view of the snow on the mountains from here."><img src="photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Image 2"></a>
  <a href="photos/03.jpg" data-alt="Canyon" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="I hiked to the top of the mountain and got this picture of the canyon and trees below."><img src="photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Image 3"></a>
  <a href="photos/04.jpg" data-alt="Iceberg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="It was amazing to see an iceberg up close, it was so cold but didn’t snow today. "><img src="photos/thumbnails/04.jpg" alt="Image 4"></a>
  <a href="photos/05.jpg" data-alt="Desert" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="The red cliffs were beautiful. It was really hot in the desert but we did a lot of walking through the canyons."><img src="photos/thumbnails/05.jpg" alt="Image 5"></a>
  <a href="photos/06.jpg" data-alt="Fall" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Fall is coming, I love when the leaves on the trees start to change color."><img src="photos/thumbnails/06.jpg" alt="Image 6"></a>
  <a href="photos/07.jpg" data-alt="Plantation" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="I drove past this plantation yesterday, everything is so green!"><img src="photos/thumbnails/07.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
  <a href="photos/08.jpg" data-alt="Dunes" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My summer vacation to the Oregon Coast. I love the sandy dunes!"><img src="photos/thumbnails/08.jpg" alt="Image 8"></a>
  <a href="photos/09.jpg" data-alt="Countryside Lane" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="We enjoyed a quiet stroll down this countryside lane."><img src="photos/thumbnails/09.jpg" alt="Image 9"></a>
  <a href="photos/10.jpg" data-alt="Sunset" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Sunset at the coast! The sky turned a lovely shade of orange."><img src="photos/thumbnails/10.jpg" alt="Image 10"></a>
  <a href="photos/11.jpg" data-alt="Cave" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="I did a tour of a cave today and the view of the landscape below was breathtaking."><img src="photos/thumbnails/11.jpg" alt="Image 11"></a>
  <a href="photos/12.jpg" data-alt="Blueballs" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="I walked through this meadow of bluebells and got a good view of the snow on the mountain before the fog came in."><img src="photos/thumbnails/12.jpg" alt="Image 12"></a>
</div>
```

**Option 2:** Or you can use `filter` to filter the `a` elements, like:

```
$("#site-search").keyup(function() {
  let searchInput = $("#site-search").val().toLowerCase();
  $('.images-container > a').hide().filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-title').toLowerCase().includes(searchInput);
  }).show();
});
```

```js
$("#site-search").keyup(function() {
  let searchInput = $("#site-search").val().toLowerCase();
  $('.images-container > a').hide().filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-title').toLowerCase().includes(searchInput);
  }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="site-search" placeholder="Search(16pt)">

<div class="images-container">
  <a href="photos/01.jpg" data-alt="Hay Bales" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the countryside past some straw fields."><img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Image 1"></a>
  <a href="photos/02.jpg" data-alt="Lake" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="The lake was so calm today. We had a great view of the snow on the mountains from here."><img src="photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Image 2"></a>
  <a href="photos/03.jpg" data-alt="Canyon" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="I hiked to the top of the mountain and got this picture of the canyon and trees below."><img src="photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Image 3"></a>
  <a href="photos/04.jpg" data-alt="Iceberg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="It was amazing to see an iceberg up close, it was so cold but didn’t snow today. "><img src="photos/thumbnails/04.jpg" alt="Image 4"></a>
  <a href="photos/05.jpg" data-alt="Desert" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="The red cliffs were beautiful. It was really hot in the desert but we did a lot of walking through the canyons."><img src="photos/thumbnails/05.jpg" alt="Image 5"></a>
  <a href="photos/06.jpg" data-alt="Fall" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Fall is coming, I love when the leaves on the trees start to change color."><img src="photos/thumbnails/06.jpg" alt="Image 6"></a>
  <a href="photos/07.jpg" data-alt="Plantation" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="I drove past this plantation yesterday, everything is so green!"><img src="photos/thumbnails/07.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
  <a href="photos/08.jpg" data-alt="Dunes" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My summer vacation to the Oregon Coast. I love the sandy dunes!"><img src="photos/thumbnails/08.jpg" alt="Image 8"></a>
  <a href="photos/09.jpg" data-alt="Countryside Lane" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="We enjoyed a quiet stroll down this countryside lane."><img src="photos/thumbnails/09.jpg" alt="Image 9"></a>
  <a href="photos/10.jpg" data-alt="Sunset" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Sunset at the coast! The sky turned a lovely shade of orange."><img src="photos/thumbnails/10.jpg" alt="Image 10"></a>
  <a href="photos/11.jpg" data-alt="Cave" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="I did a tour of a cave today and the view of the landscape below was breathtaking."><img src="photos/thumbnails/11.jpg" alt="Image 11"></a>
  <a href="photos/12.jpg" data-alt="Blueballs" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="I walked through this meadow of bluebells and got a good view of the snow on the mountain before the fog came in."><img src="photos/thumbnails/12.jpg" alt="Image 12"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What error you are getting? Im not getting any error but it is not working because you are not hiding anything. You also need to hide the `a` that is not result.

Comment: Close your browser and open it again :)

Comment: Maybe it is on the different line of code. I'm not getting an error. If you click on the error, it will open which line the error is from.

Comment: Are there any more `<a>` on the page? It is getting all the `<a>` on the document and some of them have no `data-title` attribute.

Comment: Can you try `$('.images-container > a').each...`. instead of just `$('a').each...`?

Comment: Maybe there are other `<a>` on the document.

Comment: Yes. `$('a')` will get all the `<a>` on the HTML document.  You are getting that error because some of those `<a>` have no `data-title` attribute. Therefore you cant `toLowerCase()` them

Comment: can you try `console.log( " a count: ", $('a').length );` and check the console?

Comment: You can check all the `<a>` by `console.log( " a count: ", $('a') );`